# Shape detection with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, javacv

I am working on an OMR engine. The scanned page are 4 corners (I cropped the top left corner and attached). I contoured it with red line. So I need to detect the corners (the shape marked with red contour) of scanned page to detect the zone of OMR. I want to do it with OpenCV/JavaCV, but I am new in OpenCV. I found solution like contour detection and approximation, line detection with Hought Transform, but I don't understand very well how to apply to solve my problem. Please Help. The thickness of lines are about 19px and the length is about 250 px;

[image: image from scanner]

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways to approach this. I think what you are looking for is something similar to [template matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_matching), since you know what you are looking for in each image. OpenCV has an implementation of standard [template matching](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html).

That would give you a decent start, however, it may not be robust enough to handle all kinds of scanned documents. You may want to do some [research](http://scholar.google.com/) on state-of-the-art object recognition algorithms. These tend to be highly proprietary, so don't be surprised if it is difficult to find a lot of detailed information on this topic.

Comment: The page can be a little bit scaled (smaller than original) or rotated (0.03 degrees - 1 degrees). In this case the template matching will be work?

Comment: If the shape is distinct enough from everything else on the page you should be fine. The scaling might be an issue, but again if you know everything will be scaled down, you could just scale your template.

Answer (score 1):

If your images captured in a regular way, i.e all of the same size or from specific distance, I think the following steps would help:

1. Specify your ROI(Region of Interest to the top left of the image)
2. Remove the noise (You can use erosion with specific SE size)
3. Do erosion on the image in order to get rid of thin lines
4. Use Line Hough Transform
5. Find the intersection of lines

After that you have the corner of your shape.